# Update if already exist in database using Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal-7, sql-update, sql-insert

I am trying to update my record of already exists and insert if not exist in Drupal. Below is my code:

```
       foreach ($array as $value) {
      $query = db_merge('network_drive_listing')
  ->key(array('filename' => $name))
  ->fields(array(
 'dirname' => $values['dirname'],
 'basename' => $value['basename'],
 'extension' => $value['extension'],
 'filename' => $value['filename'],
 'filetype' => $value['filetype'],
 'is_dir' => $value['is_dir'],
  ))->execute();
}
```

Instead of updating its adding records in database, where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

replace `$name` by `$value['filename']` into `array('filename' => $name)`

```
foreach ($array as $value) {
      $query = db_merge('network_drive_listing')
  ->key(array('filename' => $value['filename']))
  ->fields(array(
 'dirname' => $values['dirname'],
 'basename' => $value['basename'],
 'extension' => $value['extension'],
 'filename' => $value['filename'],
 'filetype' => $value['filetype'],
 'is_dir' => $value['is_dir'],
  ))->execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all update data into database give proper data.

In foreach() you can render key-> value type data.

```
- change this key(array('filename' => $name)) to  key(array('filename' => $value['filename']))
```